# Relating $p, E,$ and $m$ to $\gamma$ and $\beta$ (Special relativity)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics, momentum, mass-energy

In my QFT textbook this relation appeared $$\frac{p}{E + m} = \frac{\gamma - 1}{\gamma\beta},$$ where $p$ is $|\vec{p}|$, the modulus of the momentum, $E$ is the energy, $m$ the mass, $\beta = V$ (we're considering $c = 1$) and $\gamma = 1/(1 - \beta^2)$. I've tried manipulating this for a while and still can't prove it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that your expression for gamma is incorrect. It should be $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{(1 - \beta^2)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows straightforwardly from $E=\gamma m$ and $p=\gamma\beta m$.

Answer (score 1):

While @G. Smith's answer is correct and straightforward (with $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{(1 - \beta^2)}$), it might be of interest to interpret the form of this equation.

Using the substitutions in terms of hyperbolic-trigonometric functions of rapidity $\theta$: 

$\beta=\tanh\theta$, $\gamma=\cosh\theta$, and $\cosh^2\theta - \sinh^2\theta\equiv 1$ 
(so $E=m\cosh\theta$ and $p=m\sinh\theta$), 

then each side is equal to $$\tanh\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right),$$
which is associated with the hyperbolic analogue of the Weierstrass substitution.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula#Hyperbolic_identities